# How do I get the exact, floating point width of an element?

Tags: javascript, dom, floating-point

I am trying to get the exact width of a table cell. In IE9's developer toolbar, the Layout tab shows that it has a width of 203.68px, but `element.clientWidth` and other methods all report the rounded integer value of 204px.

I am trying to create another element that will line up perfectly with this table cell, but since IE8/9 (and Firefox 4 and Chrome 12) display the table cell at its true, floating point width (or perhaps semi-rounded, like 203.5px or 203.75px), my other element is slightly wider.

Comment: gag! stick to pixels. ie9 does subpixel rendering using directx.

Comment: why would you need sub-pixel accuracy?

Comment: I don't really need sub-pixel accuracy, I just need my elements to line up with each other. If IE9 is going to round `X.Y` down to `X`, then I need to know that, otherwise my element displays differently.

At any rate, I think this will suit my needs: http://vadikom.com/dailies/offsetwidth-offsetheight-useless-in-ie9-firefox4/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to use the same exact width for the other element, you may want to consider changing your markup so these elements have some kind of direct relationship.

In case of `td`, it may be a `td` in a different column, or an inner element.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that flexibility. The new elements I'm creating need to appear separately from the table in the DOM, but still line up with the columns.

Comment: @cpatik: you may use CSS to make these elements look different from the table. If they need to line up with columns, they can be placed in another `tr` that has a different style.